# Removing python and then re-installing on Mac OSX

Tags: python, macos, installation

I was wondering if anyone had tips on how to completely remove a python installation form Mac OSX (10.5.8) ... including virtual environments and its related binaries.  Over the past few years I've completely messed up the installed site-packages, virtual-environments, etc. and the only way I can see to fix it is to just uninstall everything and re-install.

I'd like to completely re-do everything and use virtualenv, pip, etc. from the beginning.

On the other hand if anyone knows a way to do this without removing python and re-installing I'd be happy to here about it.

Thanks,

Will

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just for everyone else's reference.  I found this in the Python documentation [here](http://docs.python.org/using/mac.html):

> > Mac OS X 10.5 comes with Python 2.5.1 pre-installed by Apple. If you wish, you are invited to install the
> >     most recent version of Python from the
> >     Python website
> >     (http://www.python.org). A current
> >     “universal binary” build of Python,
> >     which runs natively on the Mac’s new
> >     Intel and legacy PPC CPU’s, is
> >     available there.
>
> What you get after installing is a
>   number of things:
>
> ```
> * A MacPython 2.5 folder in your Applications folder. In here you find
> ```
>
> IDLE, the development environment that
>   is a standard part of official Python
>   distributions; PythonLauncher, which
>   handles double-clicking Python scripts
>   from the Finder; and the “Build
>   Applet” tool, which allows you to
>   package Python scripts as standalone
>   applications on your system.
>       * A framework /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework,
>   which includes the Python executable
>   and libraries. The installer adds this
>   location to your shell path. To
>   uninstall MacPython, you can simply
>   remove these three things. A symlink
>   to the Python executable is placed in
>   /usr/local/bin/.

I removed these and the `virtualenv` directories.  Then I re-installed everything and its working fine now.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to delete the packages you've installed from /Library/Python/2.*/site-packages/. I do not think any package installers will install by default to /System/Library, which should save you from needing to remove Python itself.

That said, you could also use virtualenv with --no-site-packages, and just ignore whatever packages you've installed system-wide without needing to remove them.

Comment: The problem is that when I do things like `pip install` or `easy_install` they don't end up in the actual python installation. ie `pip install numpy` succeeds but a subsequent `import numpy` fails Whether I'm doing them in `virtualenv`, base-distribution, etc.  I'm thinking I've got the symlinks messed up somehow.